# How to make a type explicitly castable to any enum

Tags: c#

I have

```
struct MyType
{
   public int value;
}
```

How can I define an `explicit` operator so that it is castable to any `enum` ? "any" means any enum in existence.

The "convertible to any possible enum" function is already possible if it is an `int` and not a `struct` containing `int`. For example I can always `(AnyEnum)myType.value`, `(SomeOtherEnum)myType.value`. But I would like to be able to do `(AnyEnum)myType` directly without digging an `int` inside. My idea is naturally, utilizing `implicit` in some way which will treat the whole thing as `int`. But unfortunately `implicit` does not support generic, so I would have to define `implicit` for every enum I wish to support.

It is fine if this involves some use of C# 7.3's `Enum` generic constraint. But it seems even with the constraint `where T : Enum` I cannot cast an `int` to `T` by `(T)value`. ("Cannot convert type `int` to `T`)

An example use case :

```
if(myValue.something == something)
{
   switch((MyEnum)myValue)
   {
       case MyEnum.A : ...
       case MyEnum.B : ...
   }
}
else if(myValue.something == something)
{
   switch((MyOtherEnum)myValue)
   {
       case MyOtherEnum.A : ...
       case MyOtherEnum.B : ...
   }
}
```

Another one,

```
if(myValue.ValidInEnum<MyEnum>(out MyEnum validEnum)) //converted from inside with some additional logic
{
   switch(validEnum)
   {
       case MyEnum.A : ...
       case MyEnum.B : ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `MyType` is no enum, just any value-type. Why should it be castable to `enum`?

Comment: Simply implement the operator (`public static explicit operator AnyEnum(MyType t) => (AnyEnum)t.value;`). What exactly is the problem? Well of course you cannot cast to `Enum`, so `AnyEnum` needs to be  a specific enum type.

Comment: Because I want to define it such that it is a wrapped `int`. For example, I might have a type called `Person` but with `implicit operator` with `string`, I can treat the whole type as if it is a `string` by pulling its name out. I thought this is the function of `implicit`/`explicit`, I think there must be a way to say my class is `int`-like.

Comment: @RenéVogt Yeah, my problem is exactly that with that approach it is not castable to any enum.

Comment: I'm assuming your actual type is more complicated than the one shown in the question, because I can't imagine any benefit of having a struct with a single int property.

Comment: But why would you want to do this? `int` also is not castable to `Enum`. As far as I know you can only cast an instance of a specific enum type to `Enum`. An `int` cannot be cast to `Enum` without being cast to a specific enum before.

Comment: It sounds like you'd like to implement a generic operator. But that's not supported in c#.

Comment: Castable to *any* enum? Including those which are `byte` based rather than `int`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "any enum"? You refer to **all** enums, e.g. `MyEnum`, but also `YourEnum` at the same time? That would mean both, `(MyEnum) myType` and `(YourEnum)myType` and even `(BindingFlags)myType` would be valid? Or do you mean a specific enum (`AnyEnum`)?

Comment: Having said his I can´t see much use on `(BindingFlags)myType`, when it actually wraps an `MyEnum`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert from an enum directly instead of having to access the "value" member of your struct, yes, it is possible, here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyType myType;
    myType.value = 1;
    MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum) myType;
    Console.WriteLine(myEnum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

enum MyEnum
{
    a = 0,
    b = 1
}

struct MyType
{
    public int value;

    public static explicit operator MyEnum(MyType myType)
    {
        return (MyEnum)myType.value;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
b
```

If you want to cast from any type of enum directly to your struct, I don't think that would be possible, you can look into generics as suggested in the other answer, or maybe write a little extension helper for your type:

```
public static class MyTypeExtensions
{
    public static T ToAnyEnum<T>(this MyType myType)
    {
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), myType.value);
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
MyType myType;
myType.value = 1;
MyEnum myEnum = myType.ToAnyEnum<MyEnum>();
MyOtherEnum myOtherEnum = myType.ToAnyEnum<MyOtherEnum>();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators

Comment: MyEnum doesn't need to inherit from int

Comment: This converts to `MyEnum`, but not *any* `enum`.

Comment: Well, he called it "AnyEnum" but in his quesiton he is doing an actual cast from (AnyEnum) using the value of the struct so I answered accordingly.

Comment: @Isma OP asked to convert to *any* enum. Of course you have to use a specific name in a code example, so `AnyEnum` is plausible. An explicit cast to a specific type like in your answer is nothing extraordinary.

Comment: OK, I clarified it in my answer. Thanks. (I borrowed your Enum.ToObject line, you got my up-vote for that ; -)

Comment: Why would you write an extension method for your *own* type?

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. The extension returns an enum according the value.

Comment: I meant: Why make an *extension* method for that if you can simply define the method inside the type itself. It's your own type after all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You cannot create a cast operator for *any* enum type, only for concrete enum types I'm afraid you would have go through the "big hassle" of doing:

```
var anyEnum = (AnyEnum)myType.value;
```

Another way would be using something like a `ToEnum` method maybe:

```
struct MyType
{
    int value;

    public T ToEnum<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), this.value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var anyEnum = myType.ToEnum<AnyEnum>();
```

You could also create an explicit cast to your value type:

```
public static explicit operator int(MyType myType)
{
    return myType.value;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var anyEnum = (AnyEnum)(int)myType;
```

I admit it's not really much shorter, but this would allow to make `value` private for example or do any other custom logic in the conversion.

**Personal Note**

I don't believe this kind of design makes much sense. It just tries to answer the original question. It was interesting to think about it.